# Possible to change settings for CTRL + SHIFT + F in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

When I use the combinations of <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to format the code in Eclipse, I don't like when it brakes the lines like this:

```
Toast.makeText(Activity_1.this, String.valueOf(numbersOfRows),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

If I want to put comment signs like // in the beginning of the line, then I have to do the same on the second line otherwise I get an error!

Is there a way to prevent braking rows like that?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can configure your formatter options in "windows/Preferences/Java/Code Style/Formatter". Click on edit your profile. Here you have "line wrapping" options.

Answer (score 3):

Set "Line width for preview window" option and "maximum line width" option in Preferences/Java/Code Style/Formatter.
Before that you should create a new profile name instead of default profile name